# It doesn't seem to be getting my index.html file in my views directory. I get an error on the localhost 3000, cannot get

Tags: node.js, angular, express

You can view my files in github at https://github.com/elmoreka/myTaskLIst.git.

It doesn't seem to be getting my index.html file in my views directory. I get an error on the localhost 3000, cannot get .

Answer (score 0):

The `index.html` is not served because the path used for `res.render()` is incorrect.

In your file `routes/index.js`, the rendered path is:

```
res.render('views/index.html');
```

However, as the view root is defined as `myTaskList/views`, the above code would try to find file `myTaskList/views/views/index.html`, which does not exist. To fix this issue, **the rendered path need to be as**:

```
res.render('index.html');
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Expressjs, **index.html** is a normal **static file** in your case, that needs to be sent from the server and **rendered at the client(browser)**. Since you haven't used any template engine (ejs) for your index page then the correct expressjs API to be used is

`res.sendFile('index.html');`

and not

`res.render('index.html'); // this is not ejs template file`.

Answer (score 0):

In `server.js` you are defining "client" as your static folder:

```
// Set Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
```

If you want to serve a static file like your `index.html` you need to move it to your static folder "client". Then you can send it to the client with `res.sendFile()`.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my code. I moved the index.html file to the client folder and added res.sendFile but I was still unable to get it to work.  Local host still says cannot get /